# How to design URL to get the data in the view using request.query_params.get

Tags: django, django-templates

How to design URL to get the data in the view using request.query_params.get in Django application.

Here is my view:

```
class BattleListByYear(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BattleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Battles.objects.all()
        year = self.request.query_params.get('year',None)
        if year is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(year__exact=year)
            return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py:

```
url(r'^year/(?P\d+)/$', BattleListByYear.as_view(), name='battle-list-by-year'),
```

and in your views you can access it by self.kwargs['year']:

```
class BattleListByYear(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BattleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Battles.objects.all()
        year = self.kwargs['year']
        if year is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(year__exact=year)
            return queryset
```

source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/